# Getting "unresolved reference array" error with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

```
from numpy import *
arr= array([1,2,3,4,5])
print (arr)
```

Error: unresolved reference array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you just:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```